# Minimum moves to destroy

Tags: algorithms

N one dimensional kingdoms are represented as intervals of the form $[a_i , b_i]$ on the real line. A kingdom of the form $[L, R]$ can be destroyed completely by placing a bomb at a point $x$ on the real line if $L ≤ x ≤ R$.

We need to determine minimum number of bombs required to destroy all the one dimensional kingdoms.

Example : Let $N=3$ and here are three kingdoms $[1,3]$, $[2,5]$ and $[6,9]$. We will need at least 2 bombs to destroy the kingdoms. In one of the possible solutions, we can place two bombs at $x = 2$ and $x = 6$. (Their can be multiple solutions but we are concern with count of bombs only and not their location.)

How to approach this problem ? Please help

Constraints : $1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5$, $0 ≤ a_i ≤ b_i ≤ 2000$

Can their be some greedy approach to solve this problem or can we take advantage of fact that points can go upto at max $2000$ ?

Comment: do you want an algorithm? are there any constraints on the algorithm? complexity?

Comment: @tzoorp Yes i require an algorithm that can run on given constraints in at max time limit of 0.5 seconds.So I think O(N) or O(Max of interval upperlimit) will run pretty fine.

Comment: I don't think you'll get an $O(n)$ algorithm, at best probably $O(n log(n))$.

Comment: This question was a part of CodeChef's January '15 Challenge, and can be seen [here](http://www.codechef.com/JAN15/problems/ONEKING). It was locked for the duration of the contest, and unlocked afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have an algorithm with $O(N \lg N)$.

You can choose smallest $b_i$ as the first $x$ (anything smaller cannot be better, anything bigger is worse as the bomb does not destroy the kingdom with smallest $b_i$), cross out all kingdoms that are destroyed by this bomb (you only have to check whether $a_i ≤ x$), than choose the smallest $b_i$ from not crossed out kingdom and so one.

In this algorithm, you have to go through all kingdoms to drop one bomb. If $a_i$ and $b_i$ are integer, you need at most $2001$ bombs—$O(N \cdot \text{Max of interval upperlimit})$. Else, you may have to destroy each kingdom by one bomb—$O(N^2)$.

You can also sort $a_i$s and $b_i$s together ($O(N \lg N)$), then go once or twice through all numbers and count not crossed out $b_i$s, crossing out $b_i$ associated with $a_i$s smaller than counted $b_i$s.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a processor scheduling problem in disguise. If you reformulate the question as each interval representing a "task", you want to determine the minimum number of non-overlapping tasks. Which has a greedy, $O(n \log(n))$ solution (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling).

You need to find the maximum number of overlapping intervals in an optimal manner.There's a greedy algorithm for that.  You first pick the interval which finishes first. Remove any intervals which overlap with this first one. Repeat until your list of intervals is empty. Now you know the minimum number of bombs you need to drop.

To prove that it's optimal we first have to prove that we need at LEAST that number of bombs - which we can do by showing that our algorithm for greedy interval selection is maximized. If you required a minimum of more bombs, then there was some other larger set of intervals which did not overlap, indicating that our algorithm was not maximized.

We then have to prove that we need NO MORE THAN the number of bombs. To show that we need to show that we can arrange the bombs such that we need no more than one bomb per kingdom in the maximum set that we picked in order to destroy ALL the other kingdoms that overlap with them. We can do this by first noting that we definitely need only one bomb for all kingdoms that overlap the first one in our list - because they're all going to overlap to the right, so we can pick some point on the right-hand side of the first kingdom to take out ALL the kingdoms which overlap with it. These are the same intervals that we removed after selecting each kingdom from the list originally. Since we only ever removed intervals which overlap on the right, we know that we only ever need one bomb per kingdom in the optimal set.